# How can i make the ship shoot bullets properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am creating a ship game where you can shoot down enemies and upgrade your ship. I have not done everything because i have a problem with the bullets.

Before we get started i would like to point out that i am currently using python 2.7 and pygame 1.9. I am aware that there are later versions of pygame and python but i started writing this before i knew that there were later versions of pygame for python 3.4.

I would also like to point out that i am a very basic coder and do not know some of the advanced things yet.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Destroyer')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)

shipW = 69
shipH = 88

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Other Functions~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#



#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~The Game~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

def game_loop():

    shipImg = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')

    face = 1 
    #The direction that the ship is facing. 
    #1 = North, 2 = East, 3 = South, 4 = West

    x = (display_width * 0.45 )#location of ship - x axis
    y = (display_height * 0.45) #location of ship - y axis

    x_change = 0 #change in location of ship - x axis
    y_change = 0 #change in locations of ship - y axis

    #Start of bullets

    #1

    lGun = x + 9 #location of left gun
    rGun = x + 59 #location of right gun

    yBul = 0 #change in location of bullet - y axis
    xBul = 0 #change in loaction of bullet - x axis

    fire = 0                           #this will record the direction of ship when bullet is fired

    #End of bullets

    ybul_change = 0
    xbul_change = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:       #the next four lines are for rotating the ship left
                    shipImg = pygame.transform.rotate(shipImg,90)
                    face -= 1
                    face = (face - 1) % 4
                    face += 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:    #the next four lines are for rotating the ship right
                    shipImg = pygame.transform.rotate(shipImg,-90)
                    face -= 1
                    face = (face + 1) % 4
                    face += 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if face == 1:
                        y_change = -5
                        x_change = 0
                    elif face == 2:
                        x_change = 5
                        y_change = 0
                    elif face == 3:
                        y_change = 5
                        x_change = 0
                    elif face == 4:
                        x_change = -5
                        y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if face == 1:
                        y_change = 5
                        x_change = 0
                    elif face == 2:
                        x_change = -5
                        y_change = 0
                    elif face == 3:
                        y_change = -5
                        x_change = 0
                    elif face == 4:
                        x_change = 5
                        y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    y_change = 0
                    x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_PAGEUP:
                    if face == 1:
                        x_change = -5
                        y_change = 0
                    elif face == 2:
                        y_change = -5
                        x_change = 0
                    elif face == 3:
                        x_change = 5
                        y_change = 0
                    elif face == 4:
                        y_change = 5
                        x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_PAGEDOWN:
                    if face == 1:
                        x_change = 5
                        y_change = 0
                    elif face == 2:
                        y_change = 5
                        x_change = 0
                    elif face == 3:
                        x_change = -5
                        y_change = 0
                    elif face == 4:
                        y_change = -5
                        x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                    fire = face                 #record direction of fire
                    if fire == 1 or fire == 3:  #if facing north or south
                        xbul_change = 0         #no movement - x axis
                        xBul = 0                #not facing east or west, location is 0
                        lGun = x + 9            #location of left gun - x axis
                        rGun = x + 59           #location of right gun - x axis
                        if fire == 1:           #if facing north
                            ybul_change = -5    #bullets go up
                            yBul = y - 10       #location of bullet when firing
                        else:
                            ybul_change = 5     #bullets go down
                            yBul = y + 88       #location of bullet when firing - y axis
                    else: #facing east or west
                        ybul_change = 0         #no movement - y axis
                        yBul = 0                #not facing north or south,location is 0
                        lGun = y + 59           #location of left gun - y axis
                        rGun = y + 9            #location of right gun - y axis
                        if fire == 2:           #if facing west
                            xbul_change = 5     #bullets are supposed to  move right but they actually move down
                            xBul = x + 88       #location of bullets, i don't know what is wrong with this but it doesn't work
                        else:
                            xbul_change = -5    #bullets are supposed to  move left but they actually move up
                            xBul = x - 10       #location of bullets, i don't know what is wrong with this but it doesn't work



        gameDisplay.fill(green)

        gameDisplay.blit(shipImg,(x,y))

        if fire == 1 or fire == 3:                                   #if facing north or south
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [lGun, yBul, 2, 10])
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [rGun, yBul, 2, 10])
        elif fire == 2 or fire == 4:                                 #if facing east or west
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, [lGun, xBul, 10, 2]) #the bullets are not drawing in the correct position and i don't know why
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, [rGun, xBul, 10, 2]) #the bullets are not drawing in the correct position and i don't know why


        yBul += ybul_change             #add the change in location of bullet to current location - y axis
        xBul += xbul_change             #add the change in location of bullet to current location - x axis

        y += y_change                   #add the change in location of the ship to the current location - y axis
        x += x_change                   #add the change in location of the ship to the current location - x axis

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)


game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

The ship will shoot bullets correctly from both guns when facing up or facing down, however, when facing left or facing right, the bullets are still next to one another instead of on top of one another like the guns and the also move up or down instead of left or right.

Here is a link to my ship: http://tinypic.com/r/2zszjv4/8

In case the other link doesn't work: http://i61.tinypic.com/2zszjv4.jpg

I don't know what is wrong with the code, I rewrote the code twice but i couldn't figure out the problem, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following section. 
Just exchange xBul's and lGun's position and you will be fine

```
    elif fire == 2 or fire == 4:                                 #if facing east or west
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, [ xBul,lGun, 10, 2]) #the bullets are not drawing in the correct position and i don't know why
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, blue, [ xBul,rGun, 10, 2]) #the bullets are not drawing in the correct position and i don't know why
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess being up till 1am didn't help me think when i was coding but it works now.

Comment: That happens. I can understand.